# How can I send an email to lots of users using a proper way in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I need some advice because I am building a subscription module. And I have a list of so many emails. Let say 1052 emails. And I have a code like this:

```
$email_list = $this->getClientEmails(); //all email for now returns 1052 valid emails
$valid_email = array();
$invalid_email = array();

if(count($email_list) > 0) {
    for($x = 0; $x < count($email_list); $x++) {
        if(valid_email($email_list[$x]['email'])) {
            $valid_email[]  = $email_list[$x]['email'];
        } 
        //get all invalid emails
        /*else {
            $invalid_email[] = array(
                'id'    =>  $email_list[$x]['id'],
                'email' =>  $email_list[$x]['email']
            );
        }*/
    }
}

$email_string = implode(',', $valid_email);


$this->email->set_mailtype("html");

$this->email->from($from, 'Sample Admin');
$this->email->to($email_string); //send an email to 1052 users
$this->email->cc('test@sampleemail.com.ph');
$this->email->subject($subj);
$this->email->message($content);

$send_mail = $this->email->send();

if($send_mail) {
    fp('success');
} else {
    fp('failed');
}
```

Is it fine if I send an email like this? Or should I make a loop to send my email to different users? Means I will not use my imploded string. I will do the sending once in every week. And also what if the sending of email suddenly stops in the middle what should I do? Do I need to resend it again? Or should I make a column in my table that will update if the email is sent or not?

Can you give me some advice about this? That's all thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay because you have a mailing list the first thing that i would recommend is that you push the script to background. Use selinium or cron for the same that way page render won't get stuck.

Once done You can send emails either way, send to multiple people or one at a time, both of them are valid and won't cause any problem. The point you need to consider here is the `SMTP` connection that you maintain.

If you are sending them all individually, you don't want to close connection to SMTP server and reconnect every time to send the mail which would only cause the overhead.

I should say that from your case the most valid way to send email is make a queue on some database preferably redis and have a task handle them in background (`cron job` if you are on cpanel or `selinium` if you own the server)

Finally this is a part that you might wanna test out. Because you have a mailing list i am guessing you don't want people to see through your whole list so check the headers when you are sending mails to all at once and if you don't see email from other users , you are good to go else send to each of them separately.

Also one final thing, emails not being delivered is usually bounced which may reflect bad on your server so have a script that flags emails that are constantly rejected and stop sending mails to the same or your `ip address` might end with bad repo and mails might end up in spam.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response about my problem. I will try to make a cron job. (I am still new about cron thing...). By the way I found some article about my problem. Can you take a look about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447471/how-to-send-emails-in-large-quantities-with-php-script-and-cronjobs

Comment: @Jerielle that question is closed so i can't answer there. Anyway the solution is pretty simple. As i said make a queue. Now assuming cron and mysql, just make a table in sql which contains all the mail that you need to send. Make a cron script in php that is called every hour. Select 100 from the table, send mail and delete those 100 rows. This will ensure that 100 mails are sent every hour. FYI I notices something about browser in there , you don't need an open browser for cron script to run :) the run in background

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) as a library on your CodeIgniter installation?

You could just do it like this:

```
if(count($email_list) > 0) {
for($x = 0; $x < count($email_list); $x++) {
    if(valid_email($email_list[$x]['email'])) {
        $mail->addAddress($email_list[$x]['email'], $x);
    } 
}
}
```

Please refer to [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps) on how to use PHPMailer.

I hope this helps, or at least that it gives you a different perspective on how can this be done.

Referring to:

> Or should I make a column in my table that will update if the email is sent or not?

Yes, I think that if you want to control if an email has been sent you should use a 1 character field on your table as a "flag" to corroborate that the email has been sent to your users.

Comment: There are a lot of possible approaches to this question, this is just a quick solution on how to do this.